# How to change default filename in the Elfeed enclosure action?

Tags: elfeed

The default filename looks like this `ubuntupodcast_s11e36.mp3`
But I want to combine the *feed* and *title*

> Feed: Ubuntu Podcast
>   Title: S11E36 – Thirty-Six Hours

The current state
`Save as: ~/storage/podcast/ubuntupodcast_s11e36.mp3`

And I want to get this state
`Save as: ~/storage/podcast/Ubuntu Podcast - S11E36 – Thirty-Six Hours.mp3`

[image]

Comment: Welcome! How does it save the mp3 file? You could find the command name via `C-h l` after saving, then find the help about that command to see if there is a way provided by that command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default file name is generated by the variable `elfeed-show-enclosure-filename-function` (Its value is a function and the function returns a filename). For example, the following does what you described

```el
(defun my-elfeed-show-enclosure-filename (entry _url-enclosure)
  (let* ((title (elfeed-entry-title entry))
         (feed (elfeed-entry-feed entry))
         (feed-title (elfeed-feed-title feed)))
    (format "%s - %s.mp3" feed-title title)))

(setq elfeed-show-enclosure-filename-function #'my-elfeed-show-enclosure-filename)
```

Comment: Thanks for the code and explanation.
How do you debug this elisp code? If I want to expand the filename and add additional information, can I debug this function in *scratch*  buffer and see the result?

Comment: @dmin I used `message` for debugging, for example, insert `(message "%s" entry)` to the function body to find out the value of `entry`.